# Having trouble with a Collatz Conjecture test in C

Tags: c, while-loop, collatz

I am trying to create a code that will take the number 2 to 100, and test each for the collatz conjecture.
 The goal is that for each number, if it is even, divide it by two, and if it is odd, then multiply it by 3 and add 1.
 It prints each step, and each number should stop testing if it reaches 1. Why doesn't it work?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number, position;
    position == 2;
    number == 2;
    while (position <= 100)
    {
        while (number != 1)
        {
            if (number % 2 == 0)
            {
                number = number/2;
                printf("%d\n", number);
            }
            else if (number % 2 != 0)
            {
                number = number*3;
                number = number + 1;
                printf("%d\n", number);
            }
        }
    position = position + 1;
    number = position;
    }
}
```

It prints recurring Os

Comment: Maybe due to using `==` instead of `=`?

Comment: It executes the same recurring 0s

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend turning compiler warnings on: `clang-7 -pthread -lm -o main main.c
main.c:6:14: warning: equality comparison result unused
      [-Wunused-comparison]
    position == 2;`. Voting to close as typographical error.

Comment: I'm using Dev-C++ and understood 0% of what you just said. My compiler options checks everything.

Comment: these two statements: `position == 2;` and `number == 2;` have no effect.  Perhaps you meant: `position = 2;` and `number = 2;`

Answer (score 0):

Fix the `==` vs `=`:

```
position = 2;
number = 2;
```

Also, the `else if` is unnecessary.  The opposite of *even* is *odd*, so a plain `else` will suffice :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have set `position` and `number` with a double equal `==` (Comparision Operator) instead of using single equal `=` (Assignment Operator) so that the algorithm is comparing them instead of assigning a value.
The assignment should look like this:

```
position = 2;
number = 2;
```

Also you can do it when you first define them:

```
int number=2, position=2;
```

Apart from that the code is correct, the only thing to highlight is that you don´t need to use `else if` because it can just be even or odd so a single `else` would be enough.

Hope I´ve helped :-)